# FB Graph API : Get post engagment and people reached

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way via Graph API to obtain engagment and people reached about a post?

I am the admin of that page, so I have a page_token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved.

The permission "**read_insights**" is needed and then just select the field "insights" of the page and there are all the stats.